# How to copy my iPhone contacts to my sim card? (without Jailbreak)

Tags: iphone

How to copy my iPhone contacts to my sim card? (without Jailbreak)

I want to go back to my Nokia phone but I was using iPhone for a Year so i have many contacts in it. Now I want to copy my all iPhone contacts to my sim. and I will use same sim in my nokia phone.

Comment: Do you have a Mac? Are your contacts synced with address book.app or iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

Ok Just tested this. if you have an iCloud account, which you can get one free using your iPhone. You can sync your contacts to it. Then export all your contacts out as a **vCard** file.

You should then be able to send or export that file from a Mac or Pc to your Nokia phone using either the free Nokia software (Mac/PC) or the Built in Bluetooth of the Mac.

To Start.

Once you have synced your contacts to iCloud, You can login to the web interface for iCloud on a web Browser on a desktop or Laptop.  Got to the Contacts view.

In the All contacts view. Select the very first contact.
[image]

Then just like any other list, hold down the **shift** key, and use the scroll bar within the contacts view to scroll right down to the last contact. And  Select it. Doing this should now highlight all the contacts in the blue selected colour.

[image]

Now you can use the Action button to export to vCard.

[image]

The file will download to you download folder, And will be named after the first contact. But the file will be a multi-contact vCard which can be sent over bluetooth of via the Nokia software to the Phone.

**Slight UPDATE**. I forgot to mention..
Of course if you have a Mac you can sync the contacts straight to the AddressBook.app, and either do the same select and export as vCard. Or again use the Nokia software for the Mac to sync to the Nokia phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of devices that talk to the phone on a 30 pin interface and can write to your SIM card. The [Cellebrite](http://www.cellebrite.com/retail-products/retail-products/ume-36pro-universal-memory-exchanger.html) line is pricey but most repair shops and cell stores carry one to do exactly what you ask if you're not looking to buy hardware yourself to accomplish the writing to the SIM memory.