# Don't want my email contacts in my contact list

Tags: applications, iphone, gmail

My native iPhone Contacts show not only my contacts with phone numbers, but also any email address I’ve ever sent an email to or received an email from. I really would rather not have email contacts save into my contact list automatically. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: are you using gmail?

Comment: @SamGiddins I am and I want to solve this problem for that situation. Ay suggestions?

Comment: gmail has an option to automatically add everyone you email to your contacts. turn that off and you should be golden.

Comment: I too was facing the same problem everyone in my address book I pulled the plug on the attempt. But now the email address I used to start the sign-up process is getting flooded with spam, and it started about a week after the sign-up debacle. It may only be a coincidence, but I doubt it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29118/8950

Answer (score 3):

In Gmail Settings, under General, check the following option:

[image: I’ll Add Contacts Myself]

Then go to Contacts and delete all the Other Contacts that were previously added automatically. Performing this action in Gmail will be faster than on your iPhone because you can select all those contacts with a single click. Then, just wait for the deletions to propagate to your iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you the see this behavior since upgrading to iOS 9. Go into *Settings* -> *Mail, Contacts, Calendars* and deactivate *Contacts Found in Mail*. In iOS 10 it is found at *Settings* -> *Contacts* where you can deactivate *Contacts Found in Apps*. This option should be above the *Import SIM Contacts* option.

This option does not really write all the addresses into the contacts, it just sorts found mail addresses to your contacts (where you can explicitly add them to the contacts database if you want). This is not permanent unless you explicitly choose to import individual addresses, so maybe you can leave this on.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings

> mail, contacts calendars 
>   select your email account 
>   you will see the tab contacts switch this to OFF. 
>   It will ask you to delete email content in your contact list.
>   Delete it.

Et voila bye bye emails in contact list.

(just FYI - it will delete ALL contacts even the PHONE contacts you have added!)

Answer (score 2):

Tap on **Phone** icon. Then tap on **contacts**. In the contacts page on the upper left hand corner there is an icon named **Group**. Tap on that and then you come to a page where the heading is : **Show all contacts** and below that there is All iCloud, All Facebook and All Yahoo etc. Just click on **All iCloud** and press **Done** on the upper right hand top corner. You will find all the emails vanish from your contacts and only the phone contacts will remain.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but what i have just done (pure trial and error) is to go into Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendar and, on each of your accounts, unselect Contacts, then import SIM contacts.

Voilà! No more random email contacts and all the numbers from your SIM! (Not sure how this will effect your email contacts when emailing but you can always sync them again if needed, I guess!)

Answer (score 0):

The iOS email contacts are saved into the Contacts app; so, the only way to remove the email addresses from your Contacts app would cause the email addresses not show up in the Mail app. If you are using Gmail, [the official Gmail app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8) could be the solution, but I have not used the Gmail app so I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your Outlook to your Contact tab and create a folder for business contacts and for personal contacts and separate them accordingly.  Then on your iPhone go into your Contacts and hit groups and you can select either folder or both and this should fix your problem.

Comment: And if the user is not using Outlook at all?  Does this still apply?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Phone then select Contacts, or select the Contacts app directly. In the upper left corner select Groups, then remove Suggested Contacts from the list of synced contacts.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to 'settings' --> 'Mail, Contacts, Calendars". Scroll down till you see "import SIM contacts". Click on that to import your phone contacts to your iPhone.

4) On your homepage, click on the Phone icon. On the contacts page, click on the 'Groups' button on the top left. Uncheck all (your email accounts), except for 'All on my iPhone'. Now click 'done', and you're all set! Go to your Contacts app directly and do the same (uncheck all email mailboxes).

If that doesn't work, try doing this:

1) Go to 'settings' --> 'Mail, Contacts, Calendars". Under 'Accounts', access each mailbox and toggle the 'contacts' option to 'off'.

2) On the same page (Mail, Contacts, Calendar), scroll down till you see "import SIM contacts". Click on that to import your phone contacts to your iPhone.

3) Now, scroll back up to 'Accounts' and toggle the 'contacts' option of all the mailboxes back to "on".

4) Go back to your homepage and click on the Phone icon. On the contacts page, click on the 'Groups' button on the top left. Uncheck all (your email accounts), except for 'All on my iPhone'. Now click 'done', and you're all set! Go to your contacts app directly and do the same (uncheck all email mailboxes).

Answer (score 0):

I use my iPhone 5 for work and it syncs with my Outlook on my Windows PC/laptop. When I went to settings and turned off the Contacts switch for the email account it deleted all my contacts. Not a good thing. Instead, I went into Contacts and selected Groups at the top of the screen. I then deseleted Suggested Contacts. Now only the contacts that I input show up and all the random email addresses that I sent an email to once are hidden. They are still there in Suggested Contacts if I want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading all of these and started to follow the path as I too had loads of email junk contacts. Once I opened the Contact page and clicked groups I noticed three choices... All exchanges: Contact: suggested contacts. I clicked the work contacts and the other options no longer have checks next to them. Voila all the junk is gone and only my outlook contacts remain.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple, if you sync with your work Exchange outlook contacts, click on the "Phone" icon on your Iphone, in the upper left corner of the screen click on "Groups", under "EXCHANGE" make sure only "contacts" is checked.  If you have "All Exchange" checked, it will load all the email addresses as contacts in your IPhone directory.

Answer (score 0):

Install 'Delete Contacts' App free from the app store > scroll down to smart filters > scroll down and find 'no phone' > click on this and all the contact with no phone numbers will show up > delete them all and > go back to contacts and sync... all done.

Answer (score 0):

Tap Contacts, Groups , then un-tick 'All yahoo'. that's all

Answer (score 0):

Happened when I started using gmail. This worked (pasted from above):

Tap on Phone icon. Then tap on contacts. In the contacts page on the upper left hand corner there is an icon named Group. Tap on that and then you come to a page where the heading is : Show all contacts and below that there is All iCloud, All Facebook and All Yahoo etc. Just click on All iCloud and press Done on the upper right hand top corner. You will find all the emails vanish from your contacts and only the phone contacts will remain.

Let me know if it helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem on my iPhone 5s by going to Contacts, Groups, then I clicked on my email address only. It removed all my email addresses from the contacts, but kept the rest, so I didn't have to import contacts from my SIM or do anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts > Groups > uncheck any email servers (make sure there's still a check by your icloud settings). Only contacts you would have entered manually to your phone and backed up via icloud will be there.

Answer (score -1):

Just  done it, contacts, groups and check the ones you want to hide so in my case Outlook contacts, click done and they disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Its correct that you can click on Groups and then uncheck suggested contacts and it fixes the problem. However, in 15 or 20 min (Im assuming this is when the phone syncs back to exchange server) the suggested contracts gets checked again and the problem is back. Im not sure how to stop it from checking itself back on.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Contacts app. On the left side at the top you will find Groups. If you select ‘Show all contacts’ you will have all the accounts of contacts, whereas if you select only the iCloud option you will only have phone contacts.